# 3D Box Shot in Photoshop: Plugin / Template / Action / etc?

Tags: open-source, 3d, online-payment, graphic-design, photoshop

I'm trying to [learn how to make 3D Box Images in Photoshop](http://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-3d-software-box-in-photoshop-using-actions--psd-11009). I need this for box designs of different sizes, and so I found this tutorial that makes it easy to create with the use of Photoshop Actions.

Also, is there ANY software (free/paid) that can let me create these boxes hassle-free? Any Action/script/template in Photoshop that can let me change the dimensions as per requirement?

If software requires payment, please could you suggest any software within $25 range cause I don't intend to pay for a one time use for only a few boxes.

Thanks.

[image: 3D Box Image]

Comment: Ok here are couple of apps that should be useful to you: [pixologic](http://pixologic.com/sculptris/gallery/) and [wings 3D](http://www.wings3d.com/?page_id=84). Both free :-)

Comment: Ok. Thanks! I've downloaded Wings 3D, will install it later. Thanks again!

Comment: That's alright. Hope it will do what you need it too!

Answer (score 1):

[Gimp](http://www.gimp.org) is free and includes 3D transformations and scripting in either python or script-fu.  You should be able to replate the workflow that you already have in such a script and have it prompt you for the dimensions and/or text, etc. reasonably simply.